# install phantomjs / any package globally specific version

Tags: npm, phantomjs, npm-install

I want to globally install phantomjs version 1.9.8 globally.

When I ran phantomjs --version it showed me 2.1.1

So I ran `npm uninstall phantomjs -g` which was successfull.

Next when I try to run `npm install phantomjs -g 1.9.8` it is throwing me the below error

```
> npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to
> phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to
> 'phantomjs-prebuilt' npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0 npm ERR! argv
> "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phantomjs"
> "1.9.20" npm ERR! node v4.4.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR! code E404
> 
> npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on
> https://registry.npmjs.org/1.9.20 npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 '1.9.20'
> is not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to
> publish it (or use the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note
> that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http
> url, or git url.
> 
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /work/development/test-folder/npm-debug.log
```

How could I install a required version of pantomjs globally.

PS : I am not using homebrew and would like to avoid using homebrew

Answer (score 1):

After reading npm api docs, I found the solution.

`npm install -g phantomjs@version`

In general,

`npm install -g packageName@version`

use `sudo` access if you do not have permissions.

> This will work even to downgrade the package globally